# Linear approximation by rational number to $4\sqrt{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the question]

and the linear approximation answer at $x =0$ is $y = \frac1{14}x + 7$

but what can I do next to find the approximation that of the $4\sqrt{3}$ that equals the rational number??

Comment: $4\sqrt 3=\sqrt{48}$ all you have to do is plug $x=1$ in the approximation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the approximation of

$$\hat{f}(x) = \frac1{14}x+7$$

You just have to evaluate $\hat{f}(1)$ to get an approximation of $f(1)$.

Comment: i didn't really understand, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: The question was asking you to find a linear approximation of $f(x)$ of which you have done so. It then ask you to use that linear approximation to estimate $f(1)$. So you just have to evaluate $\hat{f}(1) = \frac1{14}(1)+7$.

Comment: is the answer in this case then 99/14 ?

Comment: yes. To get a feel of how good this approximation is, evaluate $\frac{99}{14}$ and $4\sqrt{3}$ and see how close they are to each other.